# Searching for SMS Campaigns

Tags: sms

I am unable to search Campaigns in my sent SMS's. It appears that the field for searching archive SMS's via campaign has disappeared

Answer (score 1):

It appears that there was a JS conflict with WPMU custom sidebars after an update to the Word Press plugin. The file was wpmu-ui.3.min.js under Word Press 4.7.3.